# how to find the last time I used my usb drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, usb

I used to have a Sandisk Ultra Fit 128GB stick plugged onto one of my USB ports of my MBP. I'm running OS X El Capitan (10.11). Today I found that my USB drive is missing.

How do I find the last time that I used my pen drive so that I could get a sense of when I lost it? I have some very important data in it so I'm dying to find it somehow! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm pretty sure that I had and used it two days back.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `system.log`. There you can find when your device has been disconnected.
 For more info: [Is there a system log which displays which external media/storage devices were connected/disconnected from my system? If so, please advise me on how to do so.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6734878)